# Analyse of an algorithm (N^2)

Tags: algorithm

I need to run an algorithm with worst-case runtime Θ(n^2). 
After that I need to run an algorithm 5 times with a runtime of Θ(n^2) every time it runs.

What is the combined worst-case runtime of these algorithms ?

In my head, the formula will look something like this:

```
( N^2 + (N^2 * 5) )
```

But when I've to analyse it in theta notation my guess is that it runs in Θ(n^2) time.

Am I right?

Comment: IIRC it doesn't matter how many times it runs, it would still be N^2 time... But school was a long time ago for me so can someone else confirm that? Also, this might be more of a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ though

Comment: `2N^2` is still O(n^2) complexity, however the equation to describe the program would obviously look different.

Comment: I wasent sure where to put this question but yes, I also believe that it will run N^2 times.

Answer (score 3):

Two times O(N^2) is still O(N^2), ten times O(N^2) is still O(N^2), five times O(N^2) is still O(N^2), any times O(N^2) is still O(N^2) as long as 'any' is a constant.

Same answer holds for \Theta instead of O.

Comment: does your answer still hold in theta notation? He doesn't want big-oh

Comment: Food for thought. If N=200 then N^2 = 40000. You say "any" number times N^2 is the same. But if that number is 200 then you have N^3

Comment: @waf  It is asymptotic notation. So we are worried about cases when n tends to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

It is `O(n^2)` regardless because what you have is basically `O(6n^2)`, which is still `O(n^2)` because you can ignore the constant. What you're looking at is something that belongs to a *set* of functions and not the function itself.

Essentially, `6n^2 ∈ O(n^2)`.

**EDIT**

You asked about Θ as well. Θ gives you the lower and upper bound, whereas O gives you the upper bound only. You only get the lower bound with Ω. Θ is the intersection of these two.

Anything that is `Θ(f(n))` is also `O(f(n))`, but not the other way round.

Comment: does your answer still hold in theta notation? He doesn't want big-oh

Comment: No worries, I myself only remember Big-Oh so wanted to make sure - i think Theta is strict, so constants do matter?

Comment: @AK4749 IIRC, big theta simply means that the function is between the upper and lower bounds, so it is between both big-o and omega. So anything that is big theta is *also* big-o, but not the other way round.